# Is there a non-obnoxious way to Doxygen a class header file?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Let's say I'm attempting to use Doxygen to document the following class header. Note that this class is purely abstract, thus I don't have a corresponding source file.

```
#ifndef QMFBANK_H
#define QMFBANK_H

#include <memory>

class QMFBank
{
    public:

        QMFBank();
        virtual void setInputReference(std::shared_ptr<double>) = 0;
        virtual std::shared_ptr<double> getLowBandReference() = 0;
        virtual std::shared_ptr<double> getHighBandReference() = 0;
        virtual void clearFilter() = 0;
        virtual void update() = 0;
};

#endif // QMFBANK_H
```

Using Doxygen, I place the following comments into the header file.

```
#ifndef QMFBANK_H
#define QMFBANK_H

#include <memory>

class QMFBank
{
    public:
        /**
         * @brief Creates a quadrature mirror filter bank
         * @param p_in A reference to an input source
         */
        QMFBank();

        /**
         * @brief Sets the reference to the QMF banks input source
         * @param p_in A reference to an input source
         */
        virtual void setInputReference(std::shared_ptr<double>) = 0;

        /**
         * @brief Retrieves a reference to the lowpassband output
         * @return Returns a shared pointer to the lowpassband output
         */
        virtual std::shared_ptr<double> getLowBandReference() = 0;

        /**
         * @brief Retrieves a reference to the highpassband output
         * @return Returns a shared pointer to the highpassband output
         */
        virtual std::shared_ptr<double> getHighBandReference() = 0;

        /**
         * @brief Clears (zeros) the filter bank history
         */
        virtual void clearFilter() = 0;

        /**
         * @brief Updates the filter bank.
         * When this method is called, the filter bank will retrieve a new input and update its outputs
         */
        virtual void update() = 0;
};

#endif // QMFBANK_H
```

However, I think this looks ugly. Yes the documentation will be quite readable within the Doxygen HTML, but it seems more difficult to read when trying to quickly reference something.

So my question: Is there a better way to write the Doxygen comments in this instance? Or is this pretty normal and I should just 'deal with it'?

Comment: The `@brief` usually isn't necessary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's autopopulated by my IDE so I just leave it in.

Comment: This is normal.

Comment: You should probably add a `virtual` destructor anyway which would give you a great opportunity to define something in a `.cpp` file :-)

Comment: You can use the `\param` syntax instead of `@param` if you think the `@` is ugly.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for the tip. I must have just have overlooked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comments like /// to get rid of two most ugly lines with /** and */ and also you can remove that @brief. Without those it looks more-or-less like OK header file.

```
#ifndef QMFBANK_H
#define QMFBANK_H
#include <memory>

/// Comment about class itself too
class QMFBank
{
public:
    /// Creates a quadrature mirror filter bank
    QMFBank();

    /// Sets the reference to the QMF banks input source
    /// @param p_in A reference to an input source
    virtual void setInputReference(std::shared_ptr<double> p_in) = 0;

    /// Retrieves a reference to the lowpassband output
    /// @return shared pointer to the lowpassband output
    virtual std::shared_ptr<double> getLowBandReference() = 0;

    /// Retrieves a reference to the highpassband output
    /// @return shared pointer to the highpassband output
    virtual std::shared_ptr<double> getHighBandReference() = 0;

    /// Clears (zeros) the filter bank history
    virtual void clearFilter() = 0;

    /// Updates the filter bank.
    /// When this method is called, the filter bank will retrieve
    /// a new input and update its outputs
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

#endif // QMFBANK_H
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on several team projects for which the written rule was, explicitely, to move all Doxygen function headers into the .cpp file.

It leaves the member functions in the .hpp file uncommented, but your IDE will fetch the documentation for you, especially in the JetBrains case. The main idea is that you are not supposed to code "real projects" using anything else than a recent IDE.

The .hpp still contains the Doxygen file & class headers though, but you can scan rapidly through the list of members, and end up with an implementation file longer than the .hpp. On the second hand, it makes "natural spacers" inside the .cpp, and somehow keeps the documentation details (@usage, @details)  where the code is read or written.

I know it contradicts most Open Source projects I've been used to read (ITK in particular), but I defend the idea that an .hpp should not be a detailed manual, but rather a concise manifest of the purpose of the class and of its interface. There can be better ways, please feel free to teach me about this.

*(BTW: I know you can configure your IDE to place separators between functions, thus avoiding walls of hundreds of code lines inside which function beginnings and ends do not stand out. I still prefer the visual input of the Doxygen header).*